# Time series DGP: No convergence to true parameter - Identification problem?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, convergence, identifiability

I set up a model, simulated some data and tried to infer the wanted parameter $\alpha$. However it seems that there may be no convergence to the true parameter (result is either $-\alpha$ or $+\alpha$). Is the following model below actually identified, i.e. does my likelihood have a global optimum?

The model looks as follows:

**Observed time series**: $S_t$, $U_t$, $p_t$

**Unobserved time series**: $S_t^*$, $U_t^*$

**Parameter to infer**: $\alpha$

**Model** :

$S_t = S_t^* + \alpha * U_{t}^**p_t, p_t \in [0,1]$

where

$S_t^* = \mu_{S} + S_{t-1}^* + \epsilon_{St}, \epsilon_{St} \sim N(0,\sigma_S)$

$U_t^* = \mu_{U} + U_{t-1}^* + \epsilon_{St},\epsilon_{Ut} \sim N(0,\sigma_U)$

with

$Cov(\epsilon_S, \epsilon_U) = 0$

**First differences of $S$ for $p=1$:**

$\Delta S = \mu_{S} + \alpha * \mu_{U} + \epsilon_{St} + \alpha*\epsilon_{Ut}$

$\Delta S \sim N(\mu_{S} + \alpha * \mu_{U}, \sqrt{\sigma_S^2 + \alpha^2 * \sigma_U^2})$ (1)

**Inference:**

Step 1: Empirical moments of $\mu_S$, $\mu_U$, $\sigma_S$, $\sigma_U$ based on observed time series with $p=0$ (first differencing and calculating mean and variance of resulting series).

Step 2: Set up log likelihood based on (1), replace $\mu$ and $\sigma$ with their empirical moments and optimize over $\alpha$.

**Result:** 
Here comes the problem. I simulated K samples with a given $\alpha$, however the optimizer converges to $-\alpha$ or $+\alpha$, although the average over all simulations is closer to $\alpha$. Depending on $\alpha$ I can mitigate the problem with choosing different optimization algorithms, however I wonder I actually may have an identification problem and the likelihood does not have a global optimum but two at -0.5 und 0.5?

Comment: Your model seems to be observationally equivalent for $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$, therefore unidentified.